# getting nested object http address

Tags: json, post, get

I have simple json obj and I want to edit it (add new nested service array element). I can access entire obj by get from http://localhost:3000/user/1/ but I also need to access service: I have tried http://localhost:3000/user/1/service but doesn't work

```
    {
  "user": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Zygmunt Stary",
      "model": "MS001",
      "serialNumber": "000001",
      "service": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "description": "nie chodzi",
          "parts": "moduł zapłonowy, gaźnik, uszczelniacze",
          "cost": "356",
          "inputDate": "2018-11-13",
          "outputDate": "2018-11-15"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Without knowing how the backend works, or if you have access to the backend, you can't really use that route. You can store the object you retrieved and take the service object from it though.

Comment: yyyyy, yup but i want to add and send to db new obj to "service" array

Comment: (edit: if it helps link to my repo :https://github.com/SkyRideRq/workshop-app)